# Long (5 second) DOMContentLoaded wait when opening PHP file

Tags: php

Thanks in advance for your help with this. I've got a very simple PHP file that returns HTML code for an image based on some passed parameters. The code works fine, and the image shows up quickly. However, the page itself doesn't finish loading for a good 5 seconds, which is interfering with some AJAX calls I'm trying to do. Firebug says the time breakdown is like this:

- 0ms: DNS lookup
- 0ms: Connecting
- 0ms: Queuing
- 211ms: Waiting for response
- 14ms: Receiving data
- +5.32s: 'DOMContentLoaded' (event)
- +5.33s: 'load' (event)

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php

$getimage = $_GET['p'];
$getcity = $_GET['c'];

?>

<img src="/images/photos/big/<?php echo $getcity; ?>_<?php echo $getimage; ?>.jpg" alt="" class="gallery" />
```

Pretty simple, no? Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Look at this, perhaps?

http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2007/09/26/shortloaded

Comment: DOMContentloaded is browser side. the entire webpage is in your memory after you the receiving data point is complete.

Comment: OK, good to know. Still, other PHP files that do the exact same thing - return content based on URL parameters - have DOMcontentloaded times of about 79ms. So why would this particular PHP code require such a long load time?

Comment: Do you load any other external files on the page? Such as advertisements, trackers or similar?

Answer (score 1):

This page is using `"/images/photos/big/"` which I assume means it's using a "big" image.  images take time to render, this is likely the slowdown.

you *might* be able to speed this up by setting the image height and width because the DOM will not know where everything is placed until the image size is known.   I am not positive if this will fix the problem, sorry.